# my python app does not run the mobil power bi embedded design

Tags: python, powerbi

I have an app where I embed power bi reports, now I have been reading that visualizations can be designed for mobile phones but I don't quite understand if it works only for the power bi app or for any app.
I modified my .js so that it would detect the screen from which the python app is viewed and accordingly update the settings when doing embedded.

From the browser console I see that my js works since it changes the layout type according to the size of the screen but when it comes to running the embedded it always shows me the desktop layout and ignores the configuration that it is taking by code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kvy0N.png)

Does anyone know why it happens?

Thank you